# django - this field is required error despite default value declared

Tags: python, django

Django error this field is required in a charfield, despite entering values the form doesnt seem to accept them. i have tried using default values for the charfield but the error persists, ran multiple migrations. attached are the screenshot and code

[image: screenshot of error]

Here is the models.py

```
class brief_download(models.Model):
    metric_choices = [
        ('insider_trans','insider_trans'),
        ('key_stats','key_stats'),
        ('news', 'news'),
        ('valuation', 'valuation_measures')
    ]
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='ITC')
    metric = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=metric_choices, default='key_stats')
```

Here is the views.py

```
def corpdata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = comp_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            co_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
            met_name = form.cleaned_data['metric']
            tick = Ticker(co_name + '.NS')
            if met_name == 'insider_trans':
                dfs = tick.insider_trans
                data = dfs
            if met_name == 'key_stats':
                dfs = tick.key_stats
                data = dfs
            if met_name == 'news':
                dfs = tick.news()
                data = dfs 
            if met_name == 'valuation':
                dfs = tick.valuation_measures()
                data = dfs
            return render(request, 'main/corpdata.html', context={'form':form, 'data':data})

    else:
        form = comp_form()
    return render(request, "main/corpdata.html", context={'form':form})
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class comp_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = brief_download
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the template.html

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" name="corpdataform">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>{{ form.as_table}}</table>
        <button type="submit" name="metric" class="btn btn-primary">Get Data</button>
        
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {% if data %}
    {{ data }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: You are not setting 'action' attribute to the form. action="{% url 'corpdata' %}"

Comment: i am already on that url, i dont want to navigate. but i'll still try the action attribut

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing from Django documentation. It does not explicitly state when to use `default` field and when not. Setting `null=True` on the field to allow null values will help clear the error

Answer (score -1):

fixed it, i rewrote the choices column and the whole form model again, and somehow it worked. If anybody can explain why it broke down or why the fix worked, please explain.

Comment: that's not a forum where you can reply to yourself and go away, you should have posted what exactly solved it or leave the question empty. Would have been great to have some information on the topic, as it looks like a bug.